# Gallery: Only one image as a thumbnail

Tags: javascript, gallery, lightbox

Here's a link: http://lomakincello.net/etu/sehen.php

---

I'm creating a website using HTML and CSS. I'm not familiar with JavaScript, so someone is helping me out with a HTML5/Flash-Player, which works fine, and a gallery.

He tried to use the original lightbox. By default, all the pictures that belong to a gallery are displayed as a thumbnail.

We would like to have several galleries (live pictures / recording sessions / miscellaneous. Something like that). **Only one picture of each gallery should be displayed as a thumbnail**. Our "webmaster" is finding that hard to achieve using the lightbox. So I'm asking you for an alternative. Do you knwo any scripts/script techniques that by default show only one picture of each gallery as a thumbnail or where a modification of the original code would be easy to do?

Comment: It shouldn't be that hard. It would help if you could post a (small) code sample of what you have, so that we can recreate your problem.

Comment: Sorry for not answering immidiately. Ire ceived this from the author of the code. The code itself follows in my next comment.I followed icio’s answer in this thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2755631/is-it-possible-to-lightbox-many-images-but-only-show-one-image-to-activate-them

The link (href=„red.jpg“) works fine without JS. When JS code is added, the lightbox opens when I click on thumb.jpg, but neither any image nor control elements are shown. Instead, whatever icon the browser uses to replace images that could not be found is shown.

Comment: in head:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="lightbox/js/jquery.1.2.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lightbox/js/jquery.lightbox.js"></script>`
-- 
in body:

`<div id="gallery1" class="gallery">
  <a href="red.jpg" title="red pic">
    <img src="thumb.jpg" width="100" height="200" alt="" />
  </a>
  <a href="green.jpg" title="green pic"></a>
</div>`  
--
just before end of body:

`<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('#gallery1').lightBox();
    $('.galleries-set1 .gallery a').lightBox();
  });
</script>`

Comment: Lol, we really need to see this working. You can post a link, or maybe make a JSfiddle.

Comment: I added a link to the opening post.

Comment: Cool. So you want to implement it that when one of those thumbnail images is clicked, you start a lightbox slide show?

Comment: Exactly, Jack. -- I don't know JS, but I understand that what my brother does is not putting anything in the node value of the anchor of the pictures that should not be displayed as thumbnails. -- It is unlikely that there is anything wrong with the lightbox files linked in the head (see comment above or follow link), right? -- Did he make any mistakes writing the code just before the end of the body (see comment above or follow link)? -- Is anything wrong with the code in the body (please notice that I adapted my brothers code, so it is not 100% identical with the code in the comment above)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you are using jQuery 1.2 and a very old lightbox script.
I would update both of these.

You can include jQuery from a CDN:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And you can get a good lightbox script with easy to follow instructions here:
http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

Then, the first thing to do, is hook up the the thumbnail to display in a lightbox:

```
<a href="large-image1.jpg" data-lightbox="images">
  <img src="http://lomakincello.net/etu/pics/00kl.jpg">
</a>
```

You can then add the other images as anchor tags, leaving them empty so that they don't display.

If you don't feel happy using empty anchor tags, you can hide them using CSS (`display: none`).

```
<a href="large-image1.jpg" data-lightbox="images">
  <img src="http://lomakincello.net/etu/pics/00kl.jpg">
</a>
<a href="large-image2.jpg" data-lightbox="images"></a>
<a href="large-image3.jpg" data-lightbox="images"></a>
```

And this should work.

The important thing to realize is that giving them the same `data-lightbox` attribute, makes them appear as part of the same show.

Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hibbard_eu/e6p4a0ra/).